# Why I cannot see packet loss on GRE over capacity tunnels?

Tags: cisco, network, snmp, iperf, traffic

I have the following topology set on *AWS* where there are 4 *CSR 1000v Routers* deployed and **Segment Routing** enabled in which the **Segment Routing Headend** is *R1* and the destination is *R3*.

I aim to send **iperf** traffic from ***Endpoint1(Client)*** to ***Endpoint2 (Server)*** with the following *SR path* = {*R1, R2, R3, R4, R3, R2, R1, R2, and R3*}. 
[image]
First of all, the traffic generated by **iperf** from ***Endpoint1*** a linearly increasing UDP traffic until I stop manually. Using **SNMP** and **Cacti** I could get throughput across the links *(GRE Tunnels)* which are summarized below.

I set all tunnels' bandwidth as **10Mbps**, I was expecting to see packet loss but I didn't. It is obvious from the plots that the throughput has exceeded the tunnels' bandwidth. However, no packet loss is recorded.

[image]
[image]

here's the tunnel's configuration:

```
interface Tunnel0
 bandwidth 10000
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis aws
 load-interval 30
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 52.27.173.12
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 isis metric 1
```

it is basically the same as the other tunnels' configuration except for the name, address and destination address.

the `show platform hardware throughput level` shows `200000000 kb/s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bandwidth command sets the reported bandwidth and is used for metric calculation only.  **It does not affect** the actual interface bandwidth.

If you want to limit bandwidth, you will need to implement traffic shaping/policing.

Comment: Thanks! would implement traffic shaping/policing help to record packet loss that happens over the tunnel?

Comment: You would see drop information in the policy you apply to the interface, not the tunnel itself.

Comment: What about the tunnel? I am actually interested to see losses on tunnels.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how things work.

Comment: Okay! Thanks Ron! One question, when I set the policies, am I able to see the loss using SNMP ?

Comment: @RonTrunk `You would see drop information in the policy you apply to the interface, not the tunnel itself.`  I beg to disagree here. If a policy map is attached to the tunnel interface (not the underlying interface carrying the tunnel), and this policy map causes drops because it does its job (i.e. shaping/policing), I'm pretty certain that these drops appear as _output discards_ of the tunnel interface, and these _are_ accessible via SNMP.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi perfect! I will try it. So literally, the policy should be attached to the tunnel interface, right?